# XAMPP does not update

Tags: xampp

I got a problem. My XAMPP Server does not update the files. It keeps showing me the 'Welcome to XAMPP' webpage which is not even in the htdocs directory anymore. I've tried different devices and it keeps showing me the default page. No errors or something. I hope anyone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you only have the one installation of XAMPP?

Comment: Cleared the browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Thanks to Carcigenicate. For some reason I installed XAMPP twice, and when I opened the htdocs folder via XAMPP it took the wrong one. If anybody got this problem check for double installs.

Comment: Good to hear. MrTux's solution would have been my next guess. Browser tend to cache pages, so while you're developing, it's helpful to turn off caching.